# Set locale to user-preferred locale except std::locale::numeric

Tags: c++, locale

Date, messages and currency should formatted in user default settings, but numbers should be parsed and printed in the "C" locale. This is the way we do it now:

```
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C");

//
// this is supposed to set the current locale but C locale for numeric and messages. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1w3527e2.aspx
std::locale loc(std::locale::empty());
std::locale loc1(loc, std::locale::classic(), std::locale::numeric);
std::locale::global(loc1);
```

Is this the correct way to set such a locale? It looks somewhat cumbersome. Also, is there a reason/case/use in setting the locale both via C's `setlocale()` and CPP's `std::locale::global()`?

Comment: How about changing the order, so you set the "global" locale first and then change the single bit you want to be different?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, do you mean first `std::locale::global()` then `setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C")`? Actually this was a bit a part of the question. Do these both work on the same locale? Or are the C locale and the CPP locale two different locales?